Feature Request: Lost Inbound Claims Handling in Amazon SP-API
I'm a developer working with the Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API) to streamline our seller operations. One critical aspect of managing our Amazon business involves dealing with lost or damaged inbound shipments to Amazon's fulfillment centers. Currently, handling these claims requires manual intervention through Seller Central, which can be time-consuming and cumbersome.
Feature Request:
I propose the addition of functionality within the SP-API specifically tailored for Lost Inbound Claims. This would enable sellers to programmatically initiate, track, and manage claims related to shipments lost or damaged in transit to Amazon's warehouses.
Key Components:
Claim Initiation: Ability to programmatically initiate a claim for a lost or damaged inbound shipment through the API.
Claim Tracking: Access to real-time status updates on initiated claims, including acknowledgment, investigation, and resolution stages.
Claim Resolution: Capability to provide necessary documentation and information to expedite the resolution process.
Notifications: Automated notifications/alerts regarding claim status changes to ensure timely follow-up and action.
Benefits:
Streamlines the claims handling process, reducing manual effort and potential errors.
Enables better visibility and control over inbound shipment issues.
Improves seller experience by providing a seamless API-driven solution for managing claims.
Use Case:
Consider a scenario where a seller ships a batch of inventory to Amazon's fulfillment center, but some units are reported missing upon arrival. With the proposed SP-API functionality for Lost Inbound Claims, the seller can programmatically initiate a claim, track its progress, and provide any necessary documentation, all without needing to log into Seller Central manually.
Request for Feedback:
I'm reaching out to the SP-API development team and the broader community for feedback on this proposed feature. Do you think this functionality would be valuable for sellers? Are there any additional considerations or features that should be included? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for considering this feature request.
